# How can I select a subset of columns from a table when relevant in an outer join?

Tags: sql, outer-join

```
select a.cust_xref_id, a.est_hour, a.phone_nbr as number, a.credit_calls, a.credit_rpcs, b.sdp_calls
from #temp0 a
full outer join #temp2 b
on a.cust_xref_id = b.sdp_cust_xref_id
and a.est_hour = b.sdp_hour
and a.phone_nbr = b.sdp_phone
```

Is there a way to get the data from table b with regard to `sdp_cust_xref_id`, `sdp_hour`, and `sdp_phone` when the data does not exist in both tables via the join? If b.sdp_calls does exist, the column values are null.

Comment: How do you know what row you want data from in `b` if the join keys don't exist??

Comment: It should be b LEFT JOIN a then, no?

Comment: @gbn - `RIGHT JOIN` since he wants data from `b` irregardless of join keys?

Comment: wait a second, aren't you already getting all rows from both in this anyways?  You are using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` so you have all rows from both tables, just add those to your `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read it a few more times and I think I know what you want.  Try this.  It will give you the values from table b if they are `NULL` in a:

```
select  COALESCE(a.cust_xref_id, b.sdp_cust_xref_id) as cust_xref_id,
        COALESCE(a.est_hour, b.spd_hour) as est_hour,
        COALESCE(a.phone_nbr, b.spd_phone) as number, 
        a.credit_calls, 
        a.credit_rpcs, 
        b.sdp_calls
from #temp0 a
full outer join #temp2 b
on a.cust_xref_id = b.sdp_cust_xref_id
and a.est_hour = b.sdp_hour
and a.phone_nbr = b.sdp_phone
```

Comment: +1 (Because I agree this appears to be the intent) But would also be nice if answer showed RIGHT JOIN and some sample results from each -- esp. with respect to the shape.

Comment: @gbn - I started to write an explanation for him in a comment when I suddenly realized what he wanted :)